# How to set vertex position resolution in the world?

Tags: vertices, snapping

When I translate/scale/rotate complex meshes its vertices are often spread in 1/1000 of a millimeter. From time to time this leads to non-manifold surfaces and other problems. I would like to be able to set the resolution of the world to let us say 1/10 of a millimeter. So all vertices are snapped to this resolution automatically. Is this possible?